# Bootstrap modal dialog in ASP Update Panel prevents input focus in tinyMCE plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the same issue as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111582/tinymce-4-links-plugin-modal-in-not-editable) although my circumstances are slightly different, none of the solutions provided work for me.

I have a bootstrap modal dialog inside an ASP update panel with a tinyMCE control which works fine apart from any modal popups from tinyMCE - all input controls are non focus-able, clicking and tabbing has no effect.

The general consensus is to use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` although this does nothing in my setup.

```
<asp:Panel ID="EditShowDetailsPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modal fade" TabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="EditShowDetailsPanel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="EditShowDetailsUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Show Details</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="ShowInfoTextBox" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                ....
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="SaveEditShowDetailsLinkButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="mceSave();" OnClick="SaveEditShowDetailsLinkButton_Click" CssClass="btn btn-success">Save Changes</asp:LinkButton>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>


<script type="text/javascript">

        function mceSave() {
            //save contents to textbox
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        }

        function pageLoad() {

            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);

            function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                //remove mce editor
                tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, 'ShowInfoTextBox');
            }

            //TinyMCE init
            $(document).ready(function () {
                tinymce.init({
                    selector: "textarea#ShowInfoTextBox",
                    menubar: false,
                    theme: "modern",
                    height: 300,
                    plugins: [
                        "link lists hr anchor media code"
                    ],
                    toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic underline | bullist numlist | link | media | code"

                });
            });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try to init tinyMCE when modal is shown (not on page load)?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @makshh - just tried this and unfortunately I have the same issue :(

Comment: Can you reproduce in a snippet/jsfiddle...?

Comment: Might be a red herring but... I found tinyMCE (which is used in a 3rd party app that I provide some support for) would sometimes (but not always!) add a class "mceNonEditable" to the text/controls within the editor.   Switch to code view to check that tinyMCE isn't sneakily inserting this class - if it is then that's your problem.  
In theory this behaviour can be switched off.  Unfortunately the switch didn't work in my specific implementation.
See... https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/noneditable/

Comment: @makshh  is right. TinyMCE has problems when init in hidden context. Try changing the selector and only init when `shown.bs.modal` event is raised by bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bootstrap modal has a feature that prevents focusing of any elements outside the modal itself. This can be seen in the Bootstrap modal code ([the  `enforceFocus` function](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/df08d95495cf3cd9278099dc91c630423eccc846/js/modal.js#L139-L149)). Since the TinyMCE dialogs are rendered outside the bootstrap modal, the modal does not allow them to be focused.

In **Bootstrap 4**, this functionality can be disabled by setting `focus: false` in the modal configuration.

In **Bootstrap 3**, this functionality cannot be suppressed. Here are two possible workarounds:

- Override the `enforceFocus` function before the Bootstrap modal is initialized, via

  ```
  $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = $.noop;
  ```

  This will disable the feature for all modals thereafter.
- Remove the focus event handler once the dialog has been initialized.

  ```
  $(document).off('focusin.bs.modal');
  ```

  This will disable the functionality in the currently opened modals, but newly opened ones will still have it.