# Getting too much recursion when using Tinymce, how can I stop this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

I'm using [Tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/) which is a html editor.

There is a known [bug](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/782) in TinyMCE which effects the ability of inserting/editing links when Tinymce is used within a Twitter Bootstrap modal (as shown in the picture below)

[image: showing the issue]

I was able to get past this by using the following code snippet

```
$(document).on('focusin', '.mce-textbox', function() {
    $(this).focus();
});
```

This however, is causing '**too much recursion**' errors.

I have created the demo below which shows the error in the console and I have also included the code which makes it work (uncomment this to make it work however, this is when I get the errors)

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1eddy87/k66k3yep/) (js fiddle)

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111582/tinymce-4-links-plugin-modal-in-not-editable)

Comment: I looked into that post before however, the answers there didn't work for me so I wrote the piece of code above. I just want to remove the too much recursion errors.