# TinyMCE 6 in Fancybox 5: Cannot focus popup

Tags: javascript, tinymce, fancybox, tinymce-6

I have a TinyMCE editor in a Fancybox 5 (inline) dialog.

The editor itself works fine, but when I click the `<>` (source code) button, the cursor doesn't appear in the box and I am unable to edit it. Interestingly, the Save and Cancel buttons are still clickable.

I found this answer on StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18209594/1333416 - but it relates to a different version of TinyMCE and Bootstrap.

Here's a pen showing the issue:

https://codepen.io/MrC1980/pen/ZEmQYvm